# Why does rails create nested resource routes with the same parameters in multiple places?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model **parent** that has many **children**, and the children belongs to a **parent**

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
end
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

I have nested the routes like this

```
resources :parents do
  resources :children
end
```

When I run the **rake routes** command, I get this:

```
parent_children    GET    /parents/:parent_id/children(.:format)          children#index
                   POST   /parents/:parent_id/children(.:format)          children#create
 new_parent_child  GET    /parents/:parent_id/children/new(.:format)      children#new
edit_parent_child  GET    /parents/:parent_id/children/:id/edit(.:format) children#edit
     parent_child  GET    /parents/:parent_id/children/:id(.:format)      children#show
                   PATCH  /parents/:parent_id/children/:id(.:format)      children#update
                   PUT    /parents/:parent_id/children/:id(.:format)      children#update
                   DELETE /parents/:parent_id/children/:id(.:format)      children#destroy
          parents  GET    /parents(.:format)                              parents#index
                   POST   /parents(.:format)                              parents#create
       new_parent  GET    /parents/new(.:format)                          parents#new
      edit_parent  GET    /parents/:id/edit(.:format)                     parents#edit
           parent  GET    /parents/:id(.:format)                          parents#show
                   PATCH  /parents/:id(.:format)                          parents#update
                   PUT    /parents/:id(.:format)                          parents#update
                   DELETE /parents/:id(.:format)                          parents#destroy
```

Notice that the **params[:id]** is different in the parents_controller than in the childrens_controller. Is there a good reason for this? Should it not just be **params[:parent_id]** and **params[:child_id]**?

Currently I can't link from one controller to another, without raising an exception:

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"parents", :id=>"3"} missing required keys: [:parent_id]
```

I do understand this error message, and I have found a not-very-pretty-hack to get around it. But how would you solve this? Am I completely missing something here?

EDIT:

The link is from **parent#show** to **children#new** and looks like this:

```
link_to 'new child', new_parent_child_path
```

Comment: Why do you need to link controllers?

Comment: I meant linking from a view in one controller to a view in another. In this example it is from the parent#show to the child#new.

Comment: Can you include the code that you're using to try to make the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= link_to 'new child', new_parent_child_path(@parent) %>
```

where `@parent` is the parent object.

is that not working for you?

I'm not sure how, but I think you are passing `:id` instead of `:parent_id` somehow.

Comment: This works and so does `<%= link_to 'new child', new_parent_child_path(@parent) %>`. Thank you

Comment: Yes, adding the .id was indeed unnecessary. Changed my answer.